# I need to know how to sort this list and remove the numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = ['2chennai','2hyderabad','4istanbul','5bogota','9barcelona']

for isalpha in x:
    sort(x)
```

Comment: The documentation sort is your friend: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `filter` function with `str.isalpha` as the test condition on the characters in the strings in `x`:

```
sorted((''.join(filter(str.isalpha, s)) for s in x))
```

This returns:

```
['barcelona', 'bogota', 'chennai', 'hyderabad', 'istanbul']
```